# Eiffel: Best practices with getters return Void if object not found?

Tags: null, void, eiffel

What is the **best practice in Eiffel to return an object from a function if not found**. I saw that many collection like ARRAY for example base the not found behaviour on precondition for example or other function.

Many languages base their politics returning Void (or null) when an object hasn't been found. In Eiffel that would imply to have a detachable object as result?

### Null politic

```
item_at_index (index: INTEGER): detachable FOO
    do
        if bar_collection.valid_index(i) then
            Result := bar_collection.item_at(i)
        else
            Result := Void 
        end
    end
```

### Never null politic

```
item_at_index (index: INTEGER): detachable FOO
    require
        bar_collection.valid_index(i)
    do
        Result := bar_collection.item_at(i)
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The policy depends on underlying structure, business logic, etc.

One example is when an element is known to be there at a particular index, key, etc. Array-like structures fall in this category. Trying to retrieve elements outside array's boundaries can be seen as an error. Therefore, having a precondition is a suitable approach.

Another example is when it's unknown whether an element is there or not. Consider an XML DOM tree and a query to get all elements of a given name. There is no prior knowledge whether such elements are present or not. Therefore, a reasonable approach is to return `Void` when no matching elements are found.

So, it is not like a black-or-white dilemma, the decision should take into account the context.